mudblazor individual component dark mode c# mudblazor
Because of my dark background mudblazor components 'i.e tables and fields' are almost invisible. I just want them to maintain their white background when on this background. Turned dark mode on to see how it would look and everything on dark colours now looks right but now where I have a white background the textboxes are invisible are a missing their outline.
Is it possible to add the dark mode attribute to a single component instead of configuring a method to be executed when I change what page I'm viewing?
EDIT:
Added an example using MudBlazor: https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/GOGovkEyooJRvjYL
I want the white paper to have the components in light mode and I want the components on the dark page to be in darkmode at the SAME time.

I don't understand what you're looking for. Could you post some code/screenshots of the UI and what you're seeing and what you expect it to be? And/or create a reproducible snippet here https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/ and add that to your question.

No simple way around this. You'll have to manually override the style of the component. or Change your global theme to match styles that meet your expectations.
